# Transferring file via thumb drive fom Ubutu 14.04 LTS to Windows 7

Tags: 14.04, windows, transfer

I want to export my Bookmarks from chrome and firefox and my documents folder from 14.04 LTS to Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

From experience there are many methods to accomplish this, but I will mention only, the simplest.
Sync your Chrome across devices, this will sync your bookmarks (http://goo.gl/vbnuxx)
Sync your Firefox also. (https://goo.gl/22KddS)
As for your My documents folder, you can just copy the contents from your My Documents folder to an external USB drive and transfer them to Win7.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, Dropbox can be installed on both Linux and Windows. It would be possible to automatically back up and share files that way. [Dropbox on Linux](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx)